# Can you find villages on Minecraft Pocket Edition?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I know Minecraft was updated somewhat recently and part of that update was to make the worlds go on forever. Did this update include villages?

Comment: @Frank Yep, good catch. I've put a small bounty on the original to motivate updating its answers.

Answer (score 0):

There are villages. I think it was either added one update earlier or on that same update with ifnite worlds.